# Should all questions about .NET Micro Framework be moved to Electronics.StackExchange.com?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

Questions about .NET Micro Framework are valid StackOverflow questions.
But I think we have a better concentration of expertise in this area in the Electronics SE site.

I posted the same question on both sites for comparison:

- SO [How to develop for .NET Micro Framework on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234329/how-to-develop-for-net-micro-framework-on-linux)
- Electronics SE [How to develop for .NET Micro Framework on Linux?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/how-to-develop-for-net-micro-framework-on-linux)

Should we close the first one? As a dupe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say No.

Questions about the `.NET Micro Framework` are pretty specific programming questions, and not necessarily bound to any hardware. If it is about interaction with embedded hardware, then yes, I think they should be migrated, but generic questions should stay on SO.

Comment: I don't see any use for .NET Micro Framework outside embedded environmets

Comment: @Jader Dias: You missed my point. There's also not much use of Vala outside Gnome, but we still don't migrate those questions to AU, because they're programming questions. Same goes for questions about the .NET MF, generic questions about it are about programming. If it comes to *direct hardware interaction*, f.e. `How can I control componentX of boardY in .NET MF` then yes, they should be migrated to ER.